# Facial Feature Detection

Tags: objective-c, computer-vision, detection

Currently working on a project with a hospital where I need to detect facial features to determine if any facial deformities exist through iPhone App.

For example I found https://github.com/auduno/clmtrackr which showed facial feature detection points. I thought maybe look at the code and make it into objective C. The problem is when I tested clmtrackr with a face with deformity it did not work as intended.

You can check it also: http://www.auduno.com/clmtrackr/clm_image.html

[image]

Also tried this image:

[image]

both were inconsistent with detecting all the features points it can detect.

Do you know of any API that could do this? Or do you know what techniques I should look up so that I can make one myself.

Thank you

Comment: hi, @jay I have the same scenarios of application in android ... I try so many libraries but it's a waste of time to get ..so could you please suggest any or share your ideas

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries for facial landmark detection:

1. Dlib ( C++ / Python )
2. CLM-Framework (C++)
3. Face++ ( FacePlusPlus ) : Web API
4. OpenCV. Here's a tutorial: http://www.learnopencv.com/computer-vision-for-predicting-facial-attractiveness/

You can read more at: http://www.learnopencv.com/facial-landmark-detection/

Answer (score 0):

you can use dlib since it's face detection algorithm is faster and it also includes a pre-trained model
https://github.com/davisking/dlib/
https://github.com/davisking/dlib-models

refer this for integration to ios [how to build DLIB for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591254/how-to-build-dlib-for-ios)

alternatively you could use openface for checking it out just download the binaries http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~tb346/software/OpenFace_0.2_win_x86.zip and you're ready to go with command lines https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace/wiki/Command-line-arguments

note:- i wont prefer to use opencv since training process and results and not so regular