# Unable to integrate Dlib library in iOS app

Tags: c++, ios, swift, dlib

I am trying to integrate dlib c++ library in my iOS project. When I add dlib I have to update compiler settings and compiler flags. I followed below guide:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53277024/1030951

Still when I try to run app, Xcode gives error saying:

```
Source/SamplePath/Sample/dlib/algs.h:17:10: "Dlib requires C++11 support.  Give your compiler the -std=c++11 option to enable it."
```

Although I have already set compiler to c++11, I face this error.

Comment: Did you successfully build dlib for iOS and are running into that error when compiling a project that uses dlib?  Or are you building dlib code as part of a project that uses it? (BTW, the error is a compile-time error, not a run-time one.) If you made any additional progress, but still running into issues, you may want to share more details of what you have tried and what the problems are, that way you are more likely to receive some help here.

Comment: Thanks. I successfully build Dlib for iOS, while compiling dlib I didn't face any error. I face above error when I add it to Xcode Project.